# How do I point 3 different variables (each form a separate array) to the same object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I found the [Assignment by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference) section in the PHP Manual. I was wondering if this would work using arrays and objects.

To my understanding, line 5 will make the three variables into arrays. Line 6 will make it so that each array [0] is a new class A but not the same class A (which means after line 8, `$arr2[0]->a` will still be 1).

```
 1  class A {
 2      public a = 1;
 3  }
 4 
 5  $arr1 = $arr2 = $arr3 = array();
 6  $arr1[0] = $arr2[0] = $arr3[0] = new A();
 7 
 8  $arr1[0]->a = 2;
```

How can I rewrite line 6 to make it so if I use line 8, `$arr2[0]->a` and `$arr3[0]->a` both equal 2? I would like to keep the constructor inline and not do this:

```
$obj = new A();

$arr1 = $arr2 = $arr3 = array();
$arr1[0] = $arr2[0] = $arr3[0] = &$a;

$arr1[0]->a = 2;
```

Comment: not sure why would you want to do this, but since all `$arr1`, `$arr2`, `$arr3` are all references to the same object, once you changed the object properties, all references should be changed too

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a little with the code. Here is the solution:

```
class A {
    public $a = 1;
}

$arr1 = $arr2 = $arr3 = array();
//This way works (I think I am going to use this, because it matches the manual)
$arr1[0] = $arr2[0] = $arr3[0] = &new A();
//This way also works
$arr1[0] = $arr2[0] = $arr3[0] = new A();

echo "1: " . $arr1[0]->a . "<br>";
echo "2: " . $arr2[0]->a . "<br>";
echo "3: " . $arr3[0]->a . "<br><br>";

$arr1[0]->a = 2;

echo "1: " . $arr1[0]->a . "<br>";
echo "2: " . $arr2[0]->a . "<br>";
echo "3: " . $arr3[0]->a . "<br>";
```

Both ways produce this:

```
1: 1
2: 1
3: 1

1: 2
2: 2
3: 2
```